# Clustering standard errors at individual and/or organisation level with fixed effects

Tags: standard-error, fixed-effects-model, clustered-standard-errors, politics

So, I have a relatively large panel dataset (26,000 observations) with data on speech by individuals belonging to political parties. The data is grouped by individual-week (i.e. an observation for individuals for each week) over the course of a number of years. I am interested in the effect of time (particularly proximity to particular events) on the type of speech used. At this stage I am probably just going to use a simple linear regression.

I am going to use *individual fixed-effects* to take into account unobserved heterogeneity across individuals, however, I'm wondering at which level to cluster my standard errors. I think it makes sense to *cluster my standard errors by political party* given the likely within-party correlation but I'm wondering if I should also (or) cluster them by *individual*?

My limited understanding suggests I should probably also cluster my standard errors at individual level but I'm not sure....